# How to send Email with Multiple Attachment in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, email, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-8.1-universal

I have some questions about sending email messages from **Windows Store Apps** (**Windows 8.1**, **C#**, **Visual Studio 2013**).

I need to:

- set recipient email address
- set subject
- set HTML content
- attach files

I am using ***Data Transfer Manager*** (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br205932) to send mails with subject, HTML content and attached files. But I can't find the way to set recipient email address.

If I don't need to set HTML content and attach files, then I can use ***mailto*** to set recipient, subject and text content. Another advantage of mailto is calling MS Outlook. But there is no way to set HTML content and, what is more important - attach files.

My questions are:

1. How to set recipient email address, if I use *Data Transfer Manager*?
2. Is there another way to send mails from Windows Store Apps, to be able to set recipient, subject, HTML content and attach files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to send email with multiple attachment this [sample](https://github.com/irfan0999/Sample/blob/master/SendMail.rar) for windows store app, this code should get you send email with.

- set recipient email address
- set subject
- set HTML content
- attach Multiple files

> [Allow less secure app Access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)  to send Email From Gmail Account.

*Click on View Raw link on Github to download Sample app.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
You said: "If you are looking to send email with multiple attachment.."
Does it change anything, if I am ok with one attachment? (because it would be better to use MS Outlook)

Comment: @VictoriaO. if you want to send multiple attachment just simply add multiple file to `List<string> myfilelist = new List<string>();
                     myfilelist.Add(file.Path);`